# tweak the django admin default permission

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I don't know if this possible, but here is what I want to achieve.

There's three default permissions in django admin. add/change/delete.

What I want is something like a "view" permission, kinda like the "change" permission but without the ability to edit.

I have a Country model, when a client is created, it needs to select a country as it's foreign key.

But if I set this field to readonly, it will not be able to select the country as I want. So I have to give the user "change" permission so that the country will be available when user create the client info.

Give the "change" permission is fine, but it would be better if it has a "view" permission.

I've done a lot search and didn't find a "perfect" solution.

I think there must be a lot of people would want this permission as well.

So how to make this custom "view" permission and integrate with django admin smoothly.

Comment: And ? What's the question exactly ?

Comment: How make such "view" permission.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions. And you'll possibly have to override a couple methods in your ModelAdmins.

Comment: thanks for the point. so I guess there's no easy way to do this. wonder why Django team never occurred to this matter.

Comment: Django is free software, so please feel free to implement the feature and contribute it back.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    readonlyfield = models.CharField(...)
    country = models.ForeignKey(...)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("change_country", "Can change country"),
        )

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'readonlyfield', 'country']

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and not request.user.has_perm('yourapp.change_country'):
            return['readonlyfield', 'country']
        else:
            return['readonlyfield']
```

So, if the user doesn't have the change_country permission, he’ll set the country field once (at creation)